# Connecting to Local Host - Android

Tags: android, sockets

I am running tomcat on my machine, and just for testing. I am trying to connect to my local host. I know that local host ip for android is 10.0.2.2. But it throws an exception saying

```
java.net.SocketException: Network Unreachable
```

How should i connect to my local host machine?

Comment: still the same exception

Comment: Do you have the Internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: If it's local host, why not try `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Maybe its just me not understanding what you're asking for. But maybe it would help if you add some details.
Tomcat is running on your Computer? And you are running an app in an emulator and try to connect from that app to your running tomcat instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I was trying it from the phone under debugging mode. works finr from emulator

Comment: I am facing same issue. How can I bring out of Debug mode? What are steps to stop debug mode for android emulator?

Answer (score 0):

used like http://10.0.2.2:8080/webservice.html